# How do I parse this json string

Tags: c#, json

I want to get the Cape URL but I'm having some trouble accessing It.

```
{
    "timestamp": <java time in ms>,
    "profileId": "<profile uuid>",
    "profileName": "<player name>",
    "signatureRequired": true, // Only present if ?unsigned=false is appended to url
    "textures": {
        "SKIN": {
            "url": "<player skin URL>"
        },
        "CAPE": {
            "url": "<player cape URL>"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried multiple json methods but I can't figure out how to do it

```cs
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic dobj = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(thestring);
object result = dobj["textures"][0]["CAPE"][0]["url"];
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to treat some objects as arrays... Did you try `dobj["textures"]["CAPE"]["url"]`? Note this answer will vary according to which libraries you are using to parse the json - so make sure you mention which one you're using in the question.

Comment: Thank you I used your code and it works you are a lifesaver.

Comment: I'll add what I said as an answer then.

Comment: Why are you using indexes (`[0]`)? Your JSON contains no arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem you are trying to treat the objects in your parsed json as some sort of array.

In both places where you've used `[0]`, it is being done on an object. This would look for a key with the name `0` which doesn't exist.

Instead, you should just use the json keys directly.

Your final code should look something like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic dobj = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(thestring);
object result = dobj["textures"]["CAPE"]["url"];
```